# Атрибут detailsElementBackground

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Всем добрый вечер. Есть вот такой код:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Может кто-нибудь популярно объяснить, что значит вот это:

```
"?android:attr/detailsElementBackground"
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут ([detailsElementBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#detailsElementBackground)) вроде написано.

Comment: Благодарствую